# Google Api For Location Finding

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-places-api

i want to make such appliction that when user enter perticular address like city name say it Ahemedabad than after clicking on search button result should be ahemdabad,gujarat,india.i don't have any backend data for it,it should be coming directly from google api based.i don't know how to do it,can any one help me on it?
Thanks in Advance
Aamirkhan I.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this [link](http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%22ahmedabad%22&sensor=false)

You will get JSON data where you can get complete address from address_components[]